# How to grep IP address and number of access

Tags: linux, monitoring, grep

I am using the following command to get the number of hits of an IP address:

```
grep "21/Jul/2013:22" /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/*/access.log | cut -d[ -f2 | cut -d] -f1 | awk -F: '{print $2":"$3}' | sort -nk1 -nk2 | uniq -c | awk '{ if ($1 > 10) print $0}'
```

This will give me the number of hits per minute. An example result is:

```
181 22:00
330 22:01
253 22:02
240 22:03
202 22:04
232 22:05
195 22:06
174 22:07
251 22:08
287 22:09
281 22:10
```

But how do I get the IP address and specify the number of hits that is greater than 100 (100 is an example only. I may specify 200 or 300)?

Example I want the following results:

```
101 22:00   192.168.1.1
80  22:00   192.168.1.2
105 22:01   192.168.1.1
115 22:01   192.168.1.2
110 22:01   192.168.1.3
```

update:

here's the sample log:

```
112.204.155.217 - - [21/Jul/2013:22:51:43 +0800] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2011/01/sinulog-150x150.png HTTP/1.1" 200 48759 "http://mysite.com/2013/05/14/may-2013-local-election-results-cebu-province-local/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36"
2.90.192.222 - - [21/Jul/2013:22:51:45 +0800] "GET /wp-content/plugins/wp-minify/min/?f=wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js,wp-content/plugins/anti-spam/js/anti-spam.js,wp-includes/js/comment-reply.min.js&m=1370437401 HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://mysite.com/2013/05/10/it-takes-a-man-and-a-woman-top-20-highest-grossing-pinoy-film/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.6; en-us; GT-S5830i Build/GINGERBREAD) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1"
2.90.192.222 - - [21/Jul/2013:22:51:45 +0800] "GET /wp-content/plugins/wp-minify/min/?f=wp-content/themes/thesis_182/style.css,wp-content/themes/thesis_182/custom/layout.css,wp-content/themes/thesis_182/custom/custom.css,wp-content/plugins/async-social-sharing/assets/css/async-share.css,wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css&m=1373070592 HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://mysite.com/2013/05/10/it-takes-a-man-and-a-woman-top-20-highest-grossing-pinoy-film/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.6; en-us; GT-S5830i Build/GINGERBREAD) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1"
112.211.182.145 - - [21/Jul/2013:22:51:49 +0800] "GET /2013/07/21/aia-de-leon-imago-failed-pass-blind-audition-the-voice-ph-video/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9960 "http://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDYQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2F2013%2F07%2F21%2Faia-de-leon-imago-failed-pass-blind-audition-the-voice-ph-video%2F&ei=mvXrUb2PFeekigfmo4HABw&usg=AFQjCNGR2knrNsMpeOn6vw1a7yyt57-IZg&sig2=sk6-hLkuluCxjNx2S-X0eg&bvm=bv.49478099,d.aGc" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
112.211.182.145 - - [21/Jul/2013:22:51:50 +0800] "GET /wp-content/plugins/wp-minify/min/?f=wp-content/themes/thesis_182/style.css,wp-content/themes/thesis_182/custom/layout.css,wp-content/themes/thesis_182/custom/custom.css,wp-content/plugins/async-social-sharing/assets/css/async-share.css,wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css&m=1373070592 HTTP/1.1" 200 7171 "http://mysite.com/2013/07/21/aia-de-leon-imago-failed-pass-blind-audition-the-voice-ph-video/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
112.211.182.145 - - [21/Jul/2013:22:51:51 +0800] "GET /wp-content/plugins/wp-minify/min/?f=wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js,wp-content/plugins/anti-spam/js/anti-spam.js,wp-includes/js/comment-reply.min.js&m=1370437401 HTTP/1.1" 200 33872 "http://mysite.com/2013/07/21/aia-de-leon-imago-failed-pass-blind-audition-the-voice-ph-video/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
222.127.42.226 - - [21/Jul/2013:22:51:59 +0800] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2011/03/Marlon-Stockinger-Filipino-Swiss-Formula-Racer-270x180.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 20345 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10B329 Safari/8536.25"
182.250.152.124 - - [21/Jul/2013:22:51:59 +0800] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2013/01/602826_10151372744414415_1480456855_n.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 99263 "-" "rarely used"
112.205.18.203 - - [21/Jul/2013:22:52:01 +0800] "GET /2013/07/18/sona-2013-traffic-advisory-re-routing-monday-july-22/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10649 "http://www.google.com.ph/search?ei=g_XrUYTyJPCZiAfB4oDQBA&q=traffic+advisory+sona+2013&oq=traffic+advisory+sona+2013&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.12...7703.33377.0.44233.61.38.12.11.13.3.270.5770.13j7j18.38.0....0...1c.1.21.mobile-gws-serp.Ekl3e2HRi4I" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10B350 Safari/8536.25"
```

Comment: Could you give some lines in your log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution for your case:

```
awk '$4 ~ /21\/Jul\/2013:22/ {print $4, $1}' test.txt | \
awk -F: '{print $2":"$3, $4}' | sed -e 's/ [0-9]* / /g' | \
sort -nk2 | sort -t":" -nk1 -nk2 | uniq -c | awk '$1 > 0'
```

The ouput procedured by your log example:

```
  1 22:51 112.204.155.217
  3 22:51 112.211.182.145
  1 22:51 182.250.152.124
  1 22:51 222.127.42.226
  2 22:51 2.90.192.222
  1 22:52 112.205.18.203
```

Replace `awk '$1 > 0'` at the end of command with number you want, i.e output with `awk '$1 > 1'`

```
  3 22:51 112.211.182.145
  2 22:51 2.90.192.222
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `awk` to cut the data. `nawk` or `gawk` are more powerful and make it easier.

Something like `awk '{print $4, $1}'` should diver you data that cut can handle easily.]]

EDIT:  Get to know the man command.  It will provide documentation on demand, faster than Google or StackExchange.  You should be able to cut and paste the following examples.

Hits per minute per IP is available with:

```
awk '$4 ~ /21\/Jul\/2013:22/ {print $4, $1}' /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/*/access.log  \
| cut -c 11-15,20- | sort | uniq -c | awk '$1 > 10 {print}'
```

If you want hit per IP, try this:

```
awk '$4 ~ /21\/Jul\/2013:22/ {print $1}' /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/*/access.log  \
| sort | uniq -c | awk '$1 > 10 {print}'
```

Your original results can do by using:

```
awk '$4 ~ /21\/Jul\/2013:22/ {print $4}' /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/*/access.log \
| cut -c 11-15 | sort | uniq -c | awk '$1 > 10 {print}'
```

Comment: Hi, I'm fairly new to linux and I'm just copying some code and test it on my server and see if it works. So I don't really know how to using awk. Can you give me the full code? thanks